# HTML5 <header> above <section> and layout issue

Tags: css, html

I want to achieve in HTML5 outliner (ie. [HTML5 outliner](https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner)) that structure:

```
1. Section 1 - heading
    1.1. Section 1 - content
2. Section 2
```

But the problem is layout:

[image: Layout]

HTML for layout could be:

```
<section class="section1">
    <header>Some content for "Section 1 - heading"</header>
    <article>Some content for "Section 1 - content"</article>
</section>
<section class="section2">Some content for "Section 2 - content"</section>
```

By far I can see 2 solutions: 1. make "Section 1 - heading" positioned absolute, 2. make "Section 2 - content" positioned absolute. Both solutions are bad. I don't want to use JavaScript to calculate the height to fix layout.

**UPDATE:
The height od header is not fixed.**

Is there any other solution for this problem? Some "special tag" or CSS trick?

**UPDATE:**

I think I found something. When you use float: left/right then parents element height is not growing, then "Section 1 - content" can have `float: left` and "Section2 - content" `float: right`. Working example: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/instead/xugzfyej/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Multiple ways to do this, easy way to work with layouts is bootstrap(http://getbootstrap.com/). I'd take a look at that, if not some simple css rules should get the layout you desire.

.section1 header{
width:100%;
height: 150px; //or whatever height you want it
float:left;
}

.section1 article{
width: 70%;
min-height:600px; //or some minimum height
float:left;

}

.section2
{
width:30%;
min-height:600px;
float:left;
}


or if you're using bootstrap do it this way:

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
My Content for the header goes here
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8"> Section One Content Goes here </div>
<div class="col-lg-4"> section 2 stuff </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated the question. I don't want the header to have fixed height. It is changing. Solution 2 is without HTML5 tags, you missed why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you use absolute positioning doesn't mean that you need to use JavaScript to calculate the positioning. [`em`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Font-relative_lengths) units come in handy here.

Here's your HTML with CSS applied to make it appear how you want. You can see the running output below.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
section {
  float: left;
}
.section1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.section2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.section1 > header {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="section1">
    <header>Some content for "Section 1 - heading that's very long"</header>
    <article>Some content for "Section 1 - content"</article>
  </section>
  <section class="section2">Some content for "Section 2 - content"</section>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I need to calculate the height. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/xugzfyej/ I have added `position: relative` for `<article>`. I dont see why 1em should help